# Recursively iterate through subdirectories and add directory to a list, if it contains any file with a specific ending

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Starting from a parent directory, I want to recursively iterate through each directory and add the directory name to a list, if it contains any file with a specific ending.

My first approach was

```
var allTestDirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>();

Directory.GetFiles(parentDirectory, "*spec.js", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .ForEach(specFile => allTestDirectories.Add(Directory.GetParent(specFile)));

var distinctTestDirectories = allTestDirectories.Distinct().ToList();
```

Which is not very nice, for various reason of which one of the most obvious is that it iterates through all files with the required ending, when it is sufficient to detect just one of them.

I assume it should be possible to do that more efficiently while still being declarative, using LINQ's `Any` function. But how would I do that?

Comment: make your own itterative function.

Comment: If you find yourself doing `new List<DirectoryInfo>()` then stop and use LINQ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not *direct*: enumerate all (sub-)directories such that contain at least one file with required ending?

```
var distinctTestDirectories = Directory
  .EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(dir => Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*spec.js").Any())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the GetParent in a select:

```
var allTestDirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>();

var distinctTestDirectories = Directory.GetFiles(parentDirectory, "*spec.js", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => Directory.GetParent(f))
    .ToList();
```